# Rails - Create parent instance from child form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parent-child, nested-forms

I'm trying to do kind of the inverse of 'accepts_nested_attributes'. I would like to create a parent instance from a 'children_controller#create'. Maybe you'll have some advice or explain me it's not relevant to do so. I'm open to every comments!

I have a Client Model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :magazine
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

And a Magazine Model:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  validates :client, :launch_date, presence: true
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end
```

I'm using react-rails gem and in `/magazines` I have a form to create a new magazine with a text field to give client name.

In my `magazines_controller.rb` I put the following

```
def create
  @client = Client.find_by_name(magazine_params[:client_id])
  @selected_magazine = Magazine.new(magazine_params)
  authorize @selected_magazine
  if @client
    @selected_magazine.client = @client
  else
    @client = Client.new(name: magazine_params[:client_id])
    @client.save
    @selected_magazine.client = @client
  end
  # @client = Client.where(name: magazine_params[:client_id]).first_or_create
  # @selected_magazine.client = @client if @selected_magazine.client_id.to_i == 0
  @title = magazine_params[:title]
  @selected_issue = nil
  @issues = nil
  @selected_magazine.save
  binding.pry
  @magazines = policy_scope(Magazine)
end

def magazine_params
  magazine_params = params.require(:magazine).permit(:title, :analytics_id, :launch_date, :client_id)
  # if @client
  #   params[:magazine][:client_id] = @client.id
  #   magazine_params.merge!(params[:magazine])
  # end
  return magazine_params
end
```

I always end up with an PG::Error:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation - ERROR:  insert or update on table "magazines" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_cd907cfe6d"
DETAIL:  Key (client_id)=(51) is not present in table "clients".
```

As if the client was not save in the database. When I `binding.pry`and call `Client.all` `after @client.save`, it does not return my new client.

I'm a bit surprised since in another project I had a similar issue and doing so was working well. For Your Information:

```
# Previous Project
# Gemfile.lock
pg (0.18.3)
rails (4.2.0)

#Current Project
# Gemfile.lock
pg (0.18.4)
rails (4.2.5.1)
```

Thanks in advance for your help. If you have any advice on good practice to create a parent instance before child from children_controller, I'm really interested.

PS1: In the controller, I tried with the commented first or create and the output is still the same. 
PS2: Let me know if you need more info on Gemfile.

Comment: Can you refer this for actual implementation of accepting nested attributes. 
https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: First, make sure you get an instance of `Client`, don't use old syntax `Client.find_by_name(magazine_params[:client_id])`, use smth like this:
`Client.where(name: magazine_params[:client_id]).first!`
Second, make sure that `Client` instance is saved, you can call `@client.save!` for this purpose.

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke, I'm trying to do the inverse of nested attributes which goes from parent to child [link(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) . If I take your example I'd like to create a user from an adress form with one-to-one association

Comment: @BitOfUniverse I tried your syntax.  `.first!` raise error as expected. And the same error is replicated, with save. The very strange thing is that it validates `@client.save` but does not add it to the db (`Client.all` does not includes the new instance')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try `inverse_of` on your associations, for example:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :magazine, inverse_of: :client
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

and

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, inverse_of: magazine
  validates :client, :launch_date, presence: true
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end
```

Further reading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations

The general use case, though, is with a `has_many`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below, this should fix the issue. I think the problem is you are trying to save the magazine before save the client. Also, you should check whether **@client.valid?** is true if not then, check **@client.errors**. Also, rewrite the controller as follows,

```
def create
  @client = Client.find_by_name(params[:magazine][:client_id])

  if @client.nil?
    @client = Client.new(name: params[:magazine][:client_id])
  end

  @selected_magazine = @client.magazines.new(magazine_params)

  authorize @selected_magazine

  @title = magazine_params[:title]
  @selected_issue = nil
  @issues = nil

  @client.save
  @magazines = policy_scope(Magazine)
end

def magazine_params
  params.require(:magazine).permit(:title, :analytics_id, :launch_date)
end
```

Comment: relations between client & mag is `has_one <=> belongs_to`so `@selected_magazine = @client.magazines.new(magazine_params)` raises error. When I split in two lines and use singulare I get a valid client and an invalid magazine (no client_id). I get `PG::ForeignKeyViolation - ERROR:  update or delete on table "clients" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_cd907cfe6d" on table "magazines"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(55) is still referenced from table "magazines".`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/. Well explained with example. It may solve your problem.

Comment: from what I've read accepts_nested_attributes only goes from parent to child. Not the reverse (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), isn't it?

Comment: that's my understanding also, although I don't understand why that is the case.  There are some use cases where you would want to create (or select an existing) parent when creating the child via the new child form.  Is there a better way of accomplishing this instead of using accepts_nested_attributes?  thx